# Why do these two execvp produce different results?

Tags: c, posix

I am wondering why the below produce different results:

```
char *const temp[] = {"cal","4","2019",NULL};


    execvp(temp[0],temp);
    perror("Return from execlp not expected");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

when executed will produce a calendar with ONLY the month april

```
char *const temp[] = {"cal"};
char *const temp2[] ={"4","2019",NULL};

    execvp(temp[0],temp2);
    perror("Return from execlp not expected");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

when executed will produce a calendar with ALL the months

I want to get the second form to work correctly, as for my problem i have 2 arrays, one to store all my commands, and the other to store all my arguments for the command. eg

```
array1[0] = command
array2[0] = arg1 ar2 arg3  // the arguments for the command in array1[0]
```

And within a loop until i hit the end of my command array use fork and excute these commands in a child class so that i can go through and execute all the commands in the array.

Comment: `argv[0]` is always assumed to be a name of the program, even if its not used by the `execvp` like in your case. The `cal` program itself starts interpreting the command line from `argv[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, how could i change it so that i can have my command in one array, arguments in another array but still execute using execvp.

Answer (score 2):

As per [execvp man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

> The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of
>   pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
>   available to the new program. ***The first argument, by convention,
>   should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.***
>   The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer

Answer (score 0):

`argv[0]` is always assumed to be a name of the program, even if its not used by the `execvp` like in your case. The `cal` program itself starts interpreting the command line from `argv[1]`. (See @kiran Biradar answer.)

You'll need to copy the (pointers to the) arguments into a bigger array, and set a dummy argument for `argv[0]`. Here's some short code to do that:

```
char **combine_args(char *arg0, char **tail) {
    size_t n = 0;
    while(tail[n]) ++n;
    char **ret = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(n+2));
    ret[0] = arg0;
    memcpy(ret + 1, tail, sizeof(char*)*n);
    ret[n+1] = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

Next you can use it like this:

```
char *const temp[] = {"cal"};
char *const temp2[] ={"4","2019",NULL};

char **argv = combine_args(temp[0], temp2);

execvp(argv[0], argv);
perror("Return from execlp not expected");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

If you do it in a loop and you can change the `temp2` array, then you can do it like this, without any allocations:

```
char *const temp[] = {"cal", "cal2", "cal3", NULL};
char *temp2[] ={NULL, "4","2019",NULL};

for(int i = 0; temp[i]; ++i)
{
    // ... fork here ...
    {
        temp2[0] = temp[i];
        execvp(temp2[0], temp2);
        perror("Return from execlp not expected");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```